# SVG to PDF rendering goes wrong - are there errors in my header?

Tags: svg

I have a couple of SVG images that I want to paste together to make a big graphic.

First, let me present you with my problem:

[image]

This is one of the symbols, placed in a grid. The grid is, for convenience, with unit-less 100 distance from line to line.
If I render it to pdf, it looks like this instead:

[image]

Those symbols have a completely wrong size for the grid (They are much larger, mostly) and they are badly positioned if I use them raw.
So my treatment is, I scale them and position them correctly in relation to the grid, then I make a rectangle around them that encompasses them completely and makes the symbol-handling easier.

That rectangle is perfectly fitting to my grid. In my case, for this symbol, it is a rectangle encompassing the six squares around the symbol. I did this, because the symbol can be rotated by the user and the rotation is done from symbol point of view; any transform after the rotation is from the rotated point of view. So I made an attempt to de-couple the transformations by wrapping them.

Finally, I move the rectangle to a user-defined place and rotate it as the user wants to have it. So far, so well, it was extensively tested in google chrome and works reliably. In Google Chrome.

Now I wanted to translate it to pdf for printing. And after conversion, the symbol is placed in the wrong position.

I am guessing (as I made several tests) that the error is somewhere in my header.

Could someone of you please check the headers that I add and tell me if and where I did something wrong? For example there is a view box starting at -100, otherwise the symbol would be cut and wrongly placed. Is there another way to "rectangularize" any arbitrary symbol? Or is it generally the wrong way to do these kinds of things?

Here are the changes that I added around the svg symbol code. Innermost changes are applied first.

```
<!-- move the rectangle to the right place and rotate it as the user wishes-->
<g transform="translate(300.0, 400.0)  rotate(0,150.0, 50.0)  ">

<!-- a rectangle around the symbol, perfectly fitting to the grid-->
<svg x="0" y="0" width="300.0" height="200.0" version = '2.0' 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-100.0 0 300.0 200.0"> 

<!-- scaled to correct size, placed inside the grid as it should be -->
<g transform =  "translate(-10.000, 73.614) scale(0.229,0.229)" >

<!-- original symbol, wrong size -->
<svg width="523" height="230" version = '2.0' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
viewBox="0 0 523 230">  
.... lots of svg paths here ...
</svg>
</g>
</svg>
</g>
```

Comment: How do you render/generate your pdf output?  (e.g by browser print option save-to-pdf, libraries like dompdf, mpdf etc.?)

Comment: I used python pdflib and the symbol moved a complete square (100 units). I used affinity designer and the symbol moved half a square. Thanks for the tip with in browser save-to-pdf, I'll try that next

Comment: It's easy for editor SVG importers to get the handling of nested `<svg>` elements wrong.  I'd recommend avoiding that if you can.  Try sticking to just transforms.  Copy the paths out of your inner `<svg>` and use a single `<g transform="">` to scale and move it to the desired location.